# Twice Synching the same Table

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync FrameWork 2.1.
I want to Sync one table twice from Source to Client with Sync Direction as UploadAndDownLoad(BiDirectional).

During first Sync I need to force one coumn as null(to counter Cyclic Constraints),
and next time I need to Sync Table.The above issue is achieved in one Direction(DownLoad).
What shall be the steps to achieve above issue.

Thanks,
Sachin K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same approach suggested below for dealing with circular references.  Some good code examples included as well.

see:  http://www.8bit.rs/blog/2009/12/replicating-self-referencing-tables-and-circular-foreign-keys-with-microsoft-sync-framework/